# "Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock" not working while "ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock"

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to figure why `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` is not working while `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` **do work**

My code is using this code:

```
this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "headerComment", "<script>NOT WORKING</script>", false);
```

*in the past it used to work*

So i tried to look for a solution for that and i did find that the master page dont contain 
`<form id="form1" runat="server">`

When i added the `form` tag `this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock`
didn't work, and then i tried to use `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, GetType(), "headerComment", "<script>WORKING</script>", false);`
And it worked.

I prefer to use `Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock` and not `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` this way i won't need to change existing working code.

I didn't find what is the differences if there are between those.. and what `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` changes will cause this change in my application.

What can be the reason that:

```
 this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "headerComment", "<script>NOT WORKING using 'Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock'</script>", false);
```

is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me is to wrap the body content of the master page
with `form` tag with `runat="server"` attribute:

```
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
  ...
  ...
  </form>
</body>
```

Then from any code behind page that runs within the master page the following code works

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(), "scriptId", "<script>console.log('working');</script>", false);
```